# How can I send an Ajax Request on button click from a form with 2 buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send a request from one page to another from a form which has 2 buttons:

```html
<form method="post">
    <button id="button_1" value="val_1" name="but1">button 1</button>
    <button id="button_2" value="val_2" name="but2">button 2</button>
    <input id="access_token" type="hidden" name="access_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['access_token']; ?>" />
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button_1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/pages/test/",
      data: {
        id: $("#button_1").val(),
        access_token: $("#access_token").val()
      },
      success: function(result) {
        alert('ok');
      },
      error: function(result) {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
  });

  $("#button_2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/pages/test/",
      data: {
        id: $("#button_2").val(),
        access_token: $("#access_token").val()
      },
      success: function(result) {
        alert('ok');
      },
      error: function(result) {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

How can I improve this code and maybe merge it into one function?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Given that the only logical difference between the handlers is the value of the button clicked, you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the element which raised the event and get the `val()` from that. Try this:

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/pages/test/",
        data: { 
            id: $(this).val(), // < note use of 'this' here
            access_token: $("#access_token").val() 
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks I'm new to Stackoverflow - currently trying to figure out things! :)

Comment: This worked. but i am trying to get pick out the `name` from my json data returned and i get undefined.   i map it this way  `alert(result.name)`

Comment: The answer to that depends entirely on how your JSON is structured. I'd suggest starting a new question for it

Answer (score 13):

Use [jQuery multiple-selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) if the only difference between the two functions is the value of the button being triggered.

```
$("#button_1, #button_2").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "/pages/test/",
        data: { id: $(this).val(), access_token: $("#access_token").val() },
        success:function(result) {
          alert('ok');
        },
        error:function(result) {
          alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a shot! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
function sendAjaxRequest(element,urlToSend) {
             var clickedButton = element;
              $.ajax({type: "POST",
                  url: urlToSend,
                  data: { id: clickedButton.val(), access_token: $("#access_token").val() },
                  success:function(result){
                    alert('ok');
                  },
                 error:function(result)
                  {
                  alert('error');
                 }
             });
     }

       $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#button_1").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              sendAjaxRequest($(this),'/pages/test/');
          });

          $("#button_2").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              sendAjaxRequest($(this),'/pages/test/');
          });
        });
```

1. created as separate function for sending the ajax request.
2. Kept second parameter as URL because in future you want to send data to different URL