# Example of AJAX Request on PHP?

Tags: java, php, ajax

I am new to AJAX Request, and my project need help.

JQuery / AJAX part :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax_save.php',]
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
            error: function(msg) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

html part :

```
<input type="text" id="txt" name="text" />
<span id="txt">Result Maybe Here</span>

<button>Get External Content</button>
```

**ajax_save.php**

```
echo base64_encode( $_GET["text"] );
```

This don't really perform well, and just silent with out any trace.

Example of performing well :

```
<input type="text" id="txt" name="text" /> >>> agnes (user type)
<span id="txt">Result Maybe Here</span> >>> YWduZXM= (result)
<button>Get External Content</button>
```

Comment: you can't `return` to the browser, try `echo` instead.  So instead of `return base64_ecode(...);` try `echo base64_ecode(...)`.  I see you deleted it, in anycase.

Comment: Yes, i deleted it. Since it maybe false or maybe running worse.

Comment: Can anyone give me full example how to perform this request.. ???

Answer (score 0):

### About Ajax

To perform AJAX request on browser(client side), you need JavaScript. Maybe you can take a look at [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). `$.get('process.php?text=something');`

To perform AJAX request in PHP(server side), use `file_get_contents('process.php?text=something');`

To make your code work, you should perform a `GET` request instead of a `POST` one:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax_save.php?text=' + $('#text').val(),
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#span').text(msg)
            }
            error: function(msg) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And every `id` in your HTML element should be unique, so they shouldn't both be `id="txt"`.

### About Base64

BTW, if you're just going to perform Base64 encoding, why not do it in JavaScript?

```js
$(function(){
    $('#text').on('input', function(){
        $('#span').text(btoa($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" name="text" />
<span id="span">Here the result!</span>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Need full example plz.. String come from user type on input tag. How to send and recieve the result

Comment: It's a JavaScript question, not PHP. Do you know how to handle onClick in JavaScript?

Comment: I know it, but if can it's not onClick but onChange. Okay for now, if user press/click button, on span appear result from process.php

Comment: No matter onClick or onChange, just send Ajax request while event triggered, and handle it after getting a result.

Comment: maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203019/how-can-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-button-click-from-a-form-with-2-buttons

Comment: noop, it's to simple or complex. I am really novice about AJAX request

Comment: This is called jQuery Ajax. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @SuryaTanamas add some Base64 example. Not sure if you'd like it.

Comment: I already fully edit my question to tell everyone whole script and the problem inside my script