# Preventing Leaflet map from reloading after submit from input-button

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i'm using leaflet to work with a map. I have a form and an

```
<input type="submit"...>
```

when i press the input-button the leaflet-map reloads and looses all layers.
the map-div is not inside the form.
how to prevent the map from reloading? 
tried

```
e.preventDefault and onsubmit="return false;"
```

any ideas?

Comment: If you don't need the submit functionality, use `<input type="button"> ` instead

Comment: I would advise to use `<button onclick="...">` instead of `<input type="submit"...>`, in the case with a button you have a full control over your form

Comment: i need the submit functionality :( i'm sending data to vb code-behind on the server

Comment: You can send it without submit, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203019/how-can-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-button-click-from-a-form-with-2-buttons

Comment: A consequence of having a 'Submit' button is that the page will reload either with the same URL or the `target`. Suggest you investigate an Ajax-based solution which submits the form data and leaves the rest of the page in place.

Answer (score -1):

You can try removing `type="submit"` attribute from  your button if you don't need the submit functionality.

Comment: The OP says they do need it do submit