# Is it possible somehow without refreshing the pages on Django to send a request via SSH to a virtual machine running Ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, ssh

Good afternoon, I have a frequently asked question, for example,

```
<button>Check</button>
```

Is it possible somehow without refreshing the page to send a request via SSH to a virtual machine running Ubuntu?

For example:

```
The csgo server is on a permanent machine, it has possible options:
IP: 192.168.44.122/94.32.143.84
PORT for SSH: 44
USER NAME: test
PASSWORD: test


Django is on local machine 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000.
```

The csgo server is started with **"./csgoserver start"**. Is it possible somehow to send a request with **"./csgoserver start"** to the local machine, on the click of a button on the page, to start the server?

I searched for information and did not find it. With the help of ajax, if I understand correctly, it is possible to send a request only if there are servers on the same machine, right? I would be grateful for the answer where should I look, what to study, so that I can implement this idea.
One guy suggested that you can look towards REST, but I can't figure out how to implement what I need through REST.

Comment: If the server hasn't started, how do you see the button?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to execute a script/program on a machine (the virtual machine) from another (here your local machine).

- Yes SSH is one way you can do that. Try `ssh -p 44 test@192.168.44.122 "csgoserver start"` (side note: I'm assuming here that the `.` in `./csgoserver start` is the user's home directory. `.` means "current directory"... that's another topic, but make sure you understand relative vs. absolute paths in unix-like systems)
- This can be done in Python from your Django view, which should receive a request (an ajax request is fine if you don't want the page to refresh) from the button click ([How can I send an Ajax Request on button click from a form with 2 buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203019/how-can-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-button-click-from-a-form-with-2-buttons#35203184)). This answer should help you with the details of using SSH in python: [Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python#3586168)

Keep security in mind before deploying this publicly though (i.e read the Django documentation on authentication, CSRF tokens etc...)